# Action before retry

Tags: c#, polly

I have this use case where, for some errors, I need to perform an action before the retry; otherwise, just retry.

Something like this:

```
try
{
action:
    <action>
}
catch (SpecialException)
{
    <cleanup>
    goto action:
}
catch (Exception)
{
    goto action:
}
```

Is this possible with Polly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

register handle with `Retry(Action<Exception, int> onRetry)`, the action will be executed before retry. so you can clear up in some case.

```
Policy.Handle<Exception>().Retry((ex, count) => {
    if(ex is NotImplementedException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("clear up");
    }
    }).Execute(() => {
        Console.WriteLine("throw exception");
        throw new Exception();//or NotImplementedException
    });
```

Comment: Yes, exactly.  The `onRetry` delegate hook in Polly is also available for every kind of retry policy (retry; retry n-times; retryforever; wait-and-retry).  And also available in async form for async executions, as the `onRetryAsync:` delegate hook.  Doco, examples: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/#retry